# Open the *Back* menu with the keyboard in firefox

Tags: firefox, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

In firefox (as well as most other browsers) you can navigate back and forward in the current tab with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>Right</kbd>. However, it's not very practical to move one at a time if you want to go back 6, 8, or 10 pages. Is there a way, in firefox, to open up the *Back/Forward* menu using the keyboard?

Just to make sure I'm clear: I'm talking about the menu opens up if you click on the little triangle immediately to the right of the *Forward* button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question, but it looks like it's not possible with a stock build of Firefox.
Here's Mozilla's list of keyboard shortcuts for Firefox, which also states there isn't any method to configure custom shortcuts build in to Firefox.

http://support.mozilla.com/en-us/kb/keyboard+shortcuts

It may however be possible with an extension, although I'm not sure if one is available to do so.

Comment: As with everything in Firefox, it's very likely that an extension covers that. I think I know of a couple extensions specifically designed to customize shortcuts. Unfortunately, I'm using Minefield here, so it's unlikely that I'll be able to test them.